# Advice on Creating Dynamic Multi-Selection HTML5 Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create a webpage (interactive form) that as the user selects drop-downs or checks radio boxes, it dynamically changes the following lists or selections and does this for a series of selections until the form is completed.  Then as the form is completed, it gives the user the option to display the completed form as a PDF to save or view.

For example, from a dropdown labeled "things" containing; pets, clothes, cars.  A user selects "pets", and a new drop-down field populates labeled "type of pets" with only a selectable list; dogs, cats, birds.  A user selects "dogs" and, and a new drop-down field populates labeled "type of dogs" with only a selectable list; bulldog, terrier, retriever. And so on...  Then, when the form is completed, an option to save or populate as a PDF.

I am not well versed in web-form terminology, so I am not sure what this type of form is called to research.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: While it doesn't seem that complex to understand, I think it's complex enough to create that you might want to look into using something like VueJS to help with this.

Comment: Can you provide samples/examples please?

Comment: Writing you the entire form you're working on is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. It especially wouldn't be appropriate for me or anyone to write you a VueJS tutorial in a Stack Overflow answer or comment.

My recommendation for you is that you check the documentation here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/. After you understand how to use Vue, then if it isn't already obvious you could come back to Stack Overflow to ask for guidance.

Comment: Samuel, thank you for the advice.  I am not looking for freebies, nor am I wanting anyone to write anything entirely for me.  I was simply asking for examples of forms you have seen written in VueJS.